# Subtleties of Non Blocking Assignments

Tags: verilog, nonblocking

Here in this example,a non-blocking assignment propagates to a continuous assignment. Can this cause any execution paradigms.Please elaborate on this piece of code- Possible errors, How can it be removed and good style of coding.

```
  always @(posedge clk)
        dff1 <= f(x);

    assign fsm_in = f(dff1);
    assign fsm_out = fsm_state;

    always @(fsm_in)
        fsm_state <= g(fsm_in);
```

Comment: f and g are arbitrary expressions just like mathematical models i.e f(x) = x2 - x + 1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, though I agree with Greg that it's better style to use blocking assignments in the combinatorial process.

On your comments:

In very simplified terms, the scheduler contains 5 queues (SV has 17), but
you're only interested in 2 of them: the `active event queue`, and the
`nonblocking assignment update queue`. In a given simulation cycle, the
simulator processes the active event queue, and then the nonblocking update
queue. In general, this will create more events, and the simulator cycles
around the queues in a pre-determined order until there are no more events at
this simulation time. The simulator then moves on to the next time at which an
event is scheduled (at the next clock edge, for example).

Assume that 4 things happen 'at once': there is a change in `fsm_state`, there
is a change in `f(x)`, and both your NBA assignments are executed. As far as
the simulator is concerned, these 4 statements are executed in the same
simulation cycle, but in an undefined order. The definition of 'at once' is
rather complex, but assume that they all happen as a result of a clock edge,
with no ordering dependencies between the statements. The simulator is usually
single-threaded, so it will actually execute the 4 statements at different
*real* times, but it knows that all 4 are expected to happen at the same
*simulation* time.

The changes on `fsm_state` and `f(dff1)` are `update events`, and are added to
the scheduler's `active event queue`.

The RHS of the two NBAs are immediately evaluated, and the LHS updates are
added to the `nonblocking assignment update queue`.

The simulator now sees a queue with 4 events on it. It executes the two active
events first, in an undefined order, so `fsm_in` and `fsm_out` get their new
values. If there are no more active events, it then executes the two
non-blocking updates, in an undefined order, so `dff1` and `fsm_state` now get
their new values.

In your case, the simulation cycle isn't finished, because the change on
`fsm_in` is also an update event, and this triggers the evaluation/execution
of the always block which is sensitive to `fsm_in`. This is an `evaluation
event`. The sim executes the always block, immediately reads the new value of
`fsm_in`, and adds the update of `fsm_state` to the NBA assignment update
queue. If there are no active events, the assignment is then acted on, and
`fsm_state` gets it's new value.

This goes on until there are no more events in this simulation cycle, and the
simulator then advances time, if something is scheduled in the future.

You could get all this from section 5 of the Verilog LRM, but it doesn't make
much sense. All the language was grafted on late in the standardisation
process and uses (VHDL) terminology that's not used elsewhere in the LRM. It
was also all added in such a way as to match the behaviour of Verilog-XL, and
specifically to document the non-determinism specific to XL, so don't expect
too much from it. NBAs weren't even added to the language till 1992, I
think. Don't bother with the SV LRM; there are many more queues, and the
common text has changed, just adding another level of confusion.

Cliff Cummings has a simplified description in one of his papers (on
non-blocking assignments), but read it with care. I'm pretty sure that the
description of the active event queue is incorrect (for RHS evaluation of
NBAs). If he was right, it would cause all sorts of problems; he presumably
got the description from an early version of the LRM.

Much the best thing to do is to look up any text on VHDL delta cycles. These
are easy to understand, and they work, and always have done, and they have
crept into Verilog over the years. The details are different, but you don't
need to know anything more than you'll find in delta cycles.

Answer (score 2):

First off: Best practice is the have non-blocking assignments for registers and blocking assignment for combination logic. I recommend taking a look at this paper: [Nonblocking Assignments in Verilog Synthesis, Coding, Styles That Kill!](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf) by Clifford E. Cummings. § 11 covers combination logic. The guidelines of the paper were for IEEE Std 1364-1995 and are still completely applicable today; Verilog and SystemVerilog.

That said, the given code as is will work functionally because you have a simple conditions. It will likely synthesize correctly too (based on Cliff's page).

You could run into problems if you use a poor coding style with a more complex designs. See [Cliff's paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf) for examples. A poor coding style also makes it harder for others to read<sup>[1]</sup>. Readable code is something you want for your professors and coworkers. An ideal linting tool would flag it as well. It is best to make yourself get into the habit of writing quality code.

<sub>*1 : See [IEEE std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 34 if you really don't want others reading your code*</sub>

Comment: I agree that using blocking assignments in combinatorial processes is 'best practice', but this is, of course, just a guideline. you can always code combinatorial logic with NBAs, and VHDL designers do this all the time. Of course, if you start using temporary variables to hold intermediate values, you have to understand what NBAs actually do, and when values update. In VHDL, you use a variable to ensure immediate update; in Verilog, you use a blocking assignment. Verilog 'guidelines' exist because the language is poorly specified - you can ignore them if you understand the language.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you ALWAYS use non-blocking for clock driven signals and blocking for combo logic (If it is RTL).  I have used many synthesizers and they show errors if you do not use the assignments as I recommended. Also there are other linting tools which also will show errors.
And I agree with Greg, that for a better readable code you should follow this guideline.

Comment: I've never seen a synthesis fail because it didn't understand NBAs, or even heard of it. This is pretty unlikely, given that they work on template recognition, and it would also mean that they couldn't handle a huge amount of VHDL code.